# How To Horizontally Center Multiple Images In An Article

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get the pictures in an article to be horizontally centered. I've tried several different techniques that I've found, but haven't had any luck.

I can post the CSS I have if it would be helpful, but I'm starting from a Dreamweaver template, so I happy to start from scratch on the CSS too.

[image: Example]

```
<article class="fluid gallery">
<h2 class="fluid showAreaH2 headingStyle">Edutech Personal del Portador</h2>
<figure class="fluid tiles zeroMargin_desktop zeroMargin_tablet"> <img src="images/mauricio.jpg" alt="Maricio"/>
  <figcaption class="textStyle">Mauricio y Rosalía Sánchez</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="fluid tiles"> <img src="images/guillermo.jpg" alt="Guillermo y Sarit"/>
  <figcaption class="textStyle">Guillermo y Sarit Llanos</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
article.fluid.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to close your <article> tag

Answer (score 0):

(Changed/edited answer)

Put both images into a wrapper and center the contents in that one:

```
<article class="fluid gallery">
    <h2 class="fluid showAreaH2 headingStyle">Edutech Personal del Portador</h2>
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <figure class="fluid tiles zeroMargin_desktop zeroMargin_tablet"> <img src="images/mauricio.jpg" alt="Maricio"/>
        <figcaption class="textStyle">Mauricio y Rosalía Sánchez</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="fluid tiles"> <img src="images/guillermo.jpg" alt="Guillermo y Sarit"/>
        <figcaption class="textStyle">Guillermo y Sarit Llanos</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!-- additional text? -->
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: When using `auto` for left and right margins a width needs to be set before it will center.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is always an option.  Set the `display` to `flex`, and `justify-content:center`.  Might need vendor prefixes for older browsers.

```css
article {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
img {
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the pictures you want centred within a doc, eg:

```
<div class="figure-wrapper">
   <figure...> ...</figure>
   ...
</div>
```

And add this css to the figure wrapper class:

```
.figure-wrapper { text-align: centre; }
```

Then you can have your text and other components aligned as required

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how easy this will be for you to implement but shouldn't be too hard.

What I suggest is having a container element for the images you want to horizontally center. Then set those images or their container elements to `display: inline-block;`.

```css
.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}
.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
    <p>
      Caption
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
    <p>
      Caption
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
    <p>
      Caption
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxrut5g1/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arathi Sreekumar, but you'll also need to add this to the CSS:

`.figure-wrapper figure { display: inline-block; }`

and you could add some padding to the `.figure-wrapper figure` tag also.